# Another word for congenial or cordial

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Someone was wrong about something. I explained to the person very kindly and with "social tact" how they were wrong and why the right answer was, in fact, the right answer. Subsequently this person became passive-aggressive in their actions. Now, I am explaining to a third party what occurred, and I want to convey that I was very cordial or congenial while explaining that the original person was incorrect, so as to say that it didn't warrant the outcome.

1. Would *congenial* be appropriate here?
2. Is *cordial* better than *congenial*? (What's the subtle difference?)
3. Is there any other word that would be better suited to convey that I was very **socially sensitive** and **friendly** in the way I presented to the person why their answer was incorrect?

Comment: I think "tactful" would be the more common word to use.

Comment: @Hellion, I was planning on saying "tactful and *congenial*", or whatever word was suggested here to replace *congenial*. I want to emphasize that I was friendly about it. *Tactful*, alone, just sounds too removed/detached.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but if someone is described as ***cordial*** I tend to assume it means they're being "friendly" because it's *polite* (but I might actually not feel very comfortable with them). Whereas a ***congenial*** person is someone who genuinely expresses goodwill and makes you feel  at ease.

Comment: IMO...congenial = friendly, cordial = respectful and following the rules of etiquette.  Sometimes you can be both of those things and the fact you're telling somebody they're wrong about something, the only thing they remember is being called out for their mistake! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez, if you'd like to add this as part of an answer, I'd like to accept it.

Comment: @KristinaLopez, also, how do you feel about Tushar's answer/comment regarding *congenial*?

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think so. Congenial means agreeable, sure, but that agreeability is because of similarities in preferences. See the [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/congenial) definition.
2. Cordial is certainly better.
3. I think you should go with **tactful and cordial.**

If you're looking for another word, I'd suggest

**decorous**

> correct and polite in a particular situation

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decorous)

> In keeping with good taste and propriety; polite and restrained

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/decorous)

Comment: You are indeed correct that Oxford's definition of *congenial* seems more about similarities in preference. But [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congenial) and [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/congenial) certainly define it more as "friendly".

Comment: @Mike: From your M-W link: Full Definition of CONGENIAL - *having the same nature, disposition, or tastes*. I always use congenial to describe someone I find friendly because we have similar tastes.

Answer (score 1):

You could go simply with **polite**.

*I politely attempted to explain that (s)he was incorrect.*

Answer (score 1):

You can say you were **diplomatic** (adj) and acted **diplomatically** (adv)

> - [**diplomatic**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diplomatic) - employing tact and conciliation especially in situations of stress.  e.g. "a diplomatic way to say no"

from the web:

[**1**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=I_5gLih6Y7MC&pg=PA76&dq=diplomatically&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAy4TT8MHZAhUSylMKHemDDEw4HhDoAQhTMAc#v=onepage&q=diplomatically&f=false) -  While engineers must be careful not to pass judgment on a particular matter, engineers who are faced with this type of ethical quandary should make every attempt to carefully, delicately, and **diplomatically** sidestep the matter in order to remove any appearance of an ethical conflict.

[**2**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=-VZNAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT98&dq=diplomatically&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju-dfk8cHZAhVK2FMKHbfLAB84RhDoAQgsMAE) - Even when Quent explained that Jenny had earlier admitted going outside and chatting with a girlfriend, all Lucy had said was, “No harm done. I know the girl means well.” As **diplomatically** as possible, Quent had proposed that the children come to live with him ...

[**3**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=IuTlifc7_n8C&pg=PT42&dq=diplomatically&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju-dfk8cHZAhVK2FMKHbfLAB84RhDoAQhEMAU) - In fact (and I don't know how to say this **diplomatically**), I don't really care whether or not people come to hear me speak anymore.

[**4**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9bWYiOhQlTcC&pg=PT27&dq=diplomatically&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii-beP88HZAhVIzlMKHQllBx84ggEQ6AEIUDAH) - I'm sure there were other ways I could've handled the situation more **diplomatically**. But you know what? Maybe not. Sometimes you have to be willing to fight for what's right.

Answer (score 0):

The neutral "**collegially**" might be best to calm down people. If colleagues is what you all are.

"Cordial" and "congenial" have too much to do with feelings, not business, at times - and this is perhaps one of those times :-)

Answer (score -2):

“Explained their answer was incorrect in a delicate fashion”
Using the word delicate indicates care and concern for the other persons Feelings and provides motivation for the deliverance

Comment: OP was asking for a 'single word' or synonym.